# How can I connect Google Cloud MySQL database to a React App

Tags: mysql, reactjs, express

I have a MySQL database present on google cloud, and I was wondering how would I be able to connect it with my ReactJS Database so that I would be able to send SQL queries to the database and receive appropriate which I can then display on the screen. I've been unable to find a good way of doing this so far.

Would using express as a middle ground be better here? Or would there be a way to connect the google cloud database directly using React?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding database in the React.JS (Client side code) would mean the connection string to your DB can be accessible into the browser, hence the DB then would not have any firewall and accept huge number of connections and that's security & performance wise is not preferred,
and yes you need to put a middle like backend, try [Fastify](https://www.fastify.io/) for example

Comment: I understand what you mean to say regarding security, however, since we'll be stopping the thing after about a month or so, along with keeping the site a secret, we aren't particularly concerned about security.

I'll look into Fastify, however, how would you go about connecting something like Express or Fastify to connect to the MySQL database on google cloud?

Comment: Sure, in the case of fastify try this plugin to connect to mysql https://github.com/fastify/fastify-mysql if you want express here is the example https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#mysql  it is super easy

Comment: Oh examples such as those would work with google cloud database as well? Would the username, password be the username and password for google cloud and the database is the name of the database?

Comment: Sure but also you need to make sure the ssl configurations are right and whitelist your ip in google's db firewall and you're ready to go